# Won't insert in mysql database because of script

Tags: javascript, jquery, sweetalert

I have a script that asks if I'm sure to add new data. My php is okay because when I want to insert data with my script disabled it inserts normally. But when my script is not disabled it will not insert anymore... I don't know why i don't get any errors (probably because there are 2 different files).

**My Script**

```js
$(document).on("click", ".btnAddSubcat", function(e) {
    event.preventDefault();
    var subcatid = $('.CatEdit-select').val();
    var subcatvalue = $('.subCat').val();
    var subcatprocedure = $('.subProcedure').val();
    var url = "../service/functions/postActions.php";
    swal({
        title: 'Add a new sub-category?',
        text: "Are you sure to Add this sub-category?",
        type: 'warning',
        showCancelButton: true,
        confirmButtonColor: '#3085d6',
        cancelButtonColor: '#d33',
        confirmButtonText: 'Yes, Add it!'
    }).then(function () {
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url : url,
            data: {
                'cat-select': subcatid,
                'subCat': subcatvalue,
                'Procedure': subcatprocedure
            },
            success: function (data) {
                swal({
                    title: 'Add!',
                    text: "You Add a sub-category!",
                    type: 'success',
                    confirmButtonColor: '#3085d6',
                    confirmButtonText: 'OK'
                }).then(function () {
                    window.location.reload();
                })
            }
        });
    })
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

if you need my php insert function or something else let me know

**EDIT**

**My PHP function**

```
function AddSubCat() {
    $Catid = $_POST['cat-select'];
    $Subnaam = $_POST['subCat'];
    $procedure = $_POST['Procedure'];

    include '../../../include/dbConnection/dbcon.php';
    //set update query ready for database, with info from the Ajax POST method for update.
    $sqladdSubCat = 'INSERT INTO `*****`(`naam`,`Werkwijze`) VALUES ("'.$Subnaam.'","'.$procedure.'")';
    //if query is done right then 'Record updated successfully'
    if (mysqli_query($conn, $sqladdSubCat))
    {
        //get new colourId
        $newUpload_id = mysqli_insert_id($conn);
        //set update query hw_algoritmes thee cat id that may have change.
        $sqlalgotime = 'INSERT INTO `*****`(`categorie_id`, `subcategorie_id`) VALUES ("'.$Catid.'","'.$newUpload_id.'")';

        //if query is done right then 'Record updated successfully'
        if (mysqli_query($conn, $sqlalgotime)) {
            //check if there is a new front image add
            if ($_FILES['HWVideo']['name'] == "") {
                //Empty
            } else {
                uploadVideoHw($_FILES['HWVideo'], $newUpload_id);
            }
        } else {
            echo "Error updating record: " . mysqli_error($conn);
        }
        header('Location: /cms/service/index.php');
    } else {
        echo "Error updating record: " . mysqli_error($conn);
        // header('Location:../../Categorieen');
    }
}
```

Comment: Add `alert()` in your Ajax success to check AJAX is working fine or not.

Comment: the alert does not work, it also effects the rest of my page

Comment: if i put the alert there the whole script won't work anymore but it will insert. it also effects some other javascript i guess

Comment: Add `alert(1);` or `console.log(1)` after this line `then(function () {` and does that works or not.

Comment: @SamiAhmedSiddiqui yes it works

Comment: @SamiAhmedSiddiqui so i guess the error is in the `ajax` but after the alert it still shows the box with succes

Comment: add `console.log(data)` after `success: function (data) {` line and check what it has.

Comment: Please provide the php as well.

Comment: @SamiAhmedSiddiqui i guess its empty

Comment: @SamiAhmedSiddiqui say if you need my text fields

Comment: You need to pass the data: subcatid, subcatvalue, subcatprocedure into the function(), I'm guessing their undefined.

Comment: @Anuga what exacly do you mean?

Comment: Do you get any errors? Check the developer console.

Comment: yes i have 2 but i have those constantly and i have a very smiliar script that works great

Comment: @xmastertje add `echo json_encode($_POST);` in your PHP function and add `console.log(data)` after `success: function (data) {`.

Comment: @SamiAhmedSiddiqui the console gives nothing

Comment: Sweet Alert isn't forwarding the data fields. You need to add them to Sweet Alert somehow so the data is forwarded to the function like = `function (data) {` or `data => {`

Comment: @Anuga can you give an example?

Comment: Look at Sweet Alerts documentation, there are several examples.